# How to SSH and run PythonOperator in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

Is there a way to ssh to a server and run a `PythonOperator` with Airflow? I am looking something like `SSHExecuteOperator` but instead of executing a bash command execute a python callable.

Comment: Where you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Its ssh privacy issue

1. goto your host ssh server and run `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and press enter all the way
2. You will get 2 rsa files.copy that file to airflow env and copy its full path
3. The Just add the below in your connection from the airflow UI

   ```
    {"key_file": "/usr/local/airflow/.ssh/id_rsa.pub", "no_host_key_check": true}
   ```

   Recompile the DAG and run it

Comment: where (in which field) would you add this in airflow UI connections?

Comment: `extra` field in Airflow UI connection